# New Relic: How to replace createTracer with startSegment

Tags: callback, trace, newrelic

I had a createTracer() method in the code which we were using in old new relic version.

```
NR.createTracer("processThread", _ => this._initialize())();
```

To migrate new relic to latest versin of New Relic, I've replaced it to startSegment() method as per new relic doc: https://github.com/newrelic/node-newrelic/blob/master/Migration%20Guide.md#upgrading-to-agent-v5

```
NR.startSegment("processThread", _ => this._initialize())();
```

But now, my code is giving me this error:

```
TypeError: NR.startSegment(...) is not a function
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I see the arguments have been changed in startSegment() and createTracer()
https://newrelic.github.io/node-newrelic/docs/API.html#createTracer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [docs](https://newrelic.github.io/node-newrelic/docs/API.html#startSegment) suggest, you have a mandatory (boolean) second parameter which you must supply:

```
NR.startSegment('mySegment', false,  _ => this._initialize())();
```

> record bool
>   Indicates if the segment should be recorded as a metric. Metrics will show up on the transaction breakdown table and server breakdown graph. Segments just show up in transaction traces.

And parameter callback is now optional, you should use third parameter [handler](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/nodejs-agent/supported-features/nodejs-custom-instrumentation) for callback

> To instrument individual callbacks, call startSegment() inside the callback, and move the main callback logic to the handler function.

Comment: But in createTracer() second argument is for callback. And in startSegment(), callback argument is the 4th one.

Comment: @user3078630 *To instrument individual callbacks, call startSegment() inside the callback, and move the main callback logic to the handler function.* see https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/nodejs-agent/supported-features/nodejs-custom-instrumentation